# Method to work out greatest volume of cube

Tags: geometry

"What is the largest possible volume of a box with rectangular faces of integer dimensions where the long diagonal $XY = 9$?"

[image]
Using the Pythagorean Theorem, $l^2+w^2=c^2$, where $c$ is the short diagonal. Using the Pythagorean Theorem again, $c^2+h^2=81$.

$c^2$ is $l^2+w^2$, so the problem is to find the integers $l, w ,h $ so that $l^2+w^2+h^2=9^2$ where the volume of the cube, $lwh$, is the largest possible volume.

I solved this problem by calculating all the possible answers and finding the largest product- $l=4, w=4, h=7$. The largest volume is 112. But in my experience, rarely *anything* in mathematics is solved where the primary method is guess and check. So my question is- how would you solve this problem without listing all the options and computing the right one?

Comment: The easiest way is to use calculus, but all that is going to tell you is that $l^2 = w^2 = h^2 = \frac{81}{3} = 27 \rightarrow l = w = h \approx 5.2$.  The largest product is going to be when all of the numbers are as large as they can be which happens at the mean (average).  If you make another number larger, it will make another smaller which will make the product smaller (for instance $5 + 5 = 10$ and $2 + 8 = 10$ but $5\cdot5 = 25$ and $2\cdot8 = 16$).  All this tells you is to look at values around $5$.  From there, because it's an integer solution, you do have to guess and test.

Comment: If not using geometry, the problem can easily be solved using optimization with Lagrange multipliers. As Jares wrote, you would arrive to $l=w=h=3 \sqrt 3$.

Comment: Hmm... So the best I can do without guess and check is an approximation?

Comment: @Joao I think so, as there is the constraint that the dimensions are integers.